# Running html parsing function over a list of URLs in R

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, supervised-learning

So I have a list/df of news article URLs that I have scraped from the 'news archives' of a local government agency - approx 5000 in all. I have written the following functions, using rvest to scrape the title, body and publication of date of the articles, which I'll include below now:

```
get_title <- function(url){

  html <- read_html(url)

  html %>%
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_first("//div[contains(@class, 'page-header col-xs-12')]") %>% 
    rvest::html_text()
}

get_text <- function(html){
  html %>% 
    rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
    xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12 text-content')]") %>% 
    rvest::html_text()
}

get_date <- function(text){
  substr(text, 14, 21)
}
```

I've tested the functions and they work fine for individual URLs, an example of which is here:

`url <- "https://www.rm.dk/om-os/aktuelt/nyheder/nyheder-2020/marts-20/aflysninger-pa-hospitalerne--tjek-din-e-boks-eller-postkasse/"`

I feel like an idiot, but I've tried every way I can think of to run the functions over my list of URLs to then create separate lists of the title, text and date of every article, which can then be combined into a tibble or df so I have the correct data for a Naive Bayes content (SML) analysis. I would be SO GRATEFUL if anyone has a suggestion for how to do this. I've tried, e.g.:

```
df_of_urls <- df_of_urls %>% mutate(title = get_title(df_of_urls$x))

get_title(list_of_urls)
```

My dataframe of URLs looks like this:

list of URLs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqUWN.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could export results of your three functions as a list and use `dplyr::bind_rows` to combine them into a tibble:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# example url list:
url1 <- "https://www.rm.dk/om-os/aktuelt/nyheder/nyheder-2020/marts-20/aflysninger-pa-hospitalerne--tjek-din-e-boks-eller-postkasse/"
url2 <- "https://www.rm.dk/om-os/aktuelt/nyheder/nyheder-2020/marts-20/guider-hjalper-ved-hospitalets-indgange/"
urls <- list(url1, url2)

get_data <- function(url){    
    html <- read_html(url)    
    title <- html %>%
        rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
        xml2::xml_find_first("//div[contains(@class, 'page-header col-xs-12')]") %>% 
        rvest::html_text()
    text <- html %>% 
        rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
        xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12 text-content')]") %>% 
        rvest::html_text()
    date <-  substr(text, 14, 21)
    return(list(title=title, text=text, date=date))
}

res <- lapply(urls, get_data) %>% bind_rows()
res
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   title                               text                                date  
#>   <chr>                               <chr>                               <chr> 
#> 1 "\n                \n             … "\n            19.03.20\nGrundet s… 19.03…
#> 2 "\n                \n             … "\n            19.03.2020\nFor at … 19.03…
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful. I figured out I stupidly had not been converting my df of URLs into a list properly, so I was getting attempting to run the code on a sublist of a list...